# tcltest unit tests: how to check if constraint is active to enable code reuse

Tags: unit-testing, tcl

We are using tcltest to do our unit testing but we are finding it difficult to reuse code within our test suite.

We have a test that is executed multiple times for different system configurations. I created a proc which contains this test and reuse it everywhere instead of duplicating the test's code many times throughout the suite.

For example:

```
proc test_config { config_name} {
    test $test_name {}  -constraints $config_name -body {
        <test body>
    } -returnCodes ok
}
```

The problem is that I sometimes want to only test certain configurations. I pass the configuration name as a parameter to the proc as shown above, but the -constraints {} part of the test does not look up the $config_name parameter as expected. The test is always skipped unless I hard code the configuration name, but using a proc is not possible and I would need to duplicate the code everywhere just to hardcode the constraint.

Is there a way to look if the constraint is enabled in the tcltest configuration?

Something like this:

```
proc test_config { config_name} {
    testConstraint X [expr { ::tcltest::isConstraintActive $config_name } ]
    test $test_name {}  -constraints X -body {
        <test body>
    } -returnCodes ok
}
```

So, is there a function in tcltest doing something like **::tcltest::isConstraintActive $config_name**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to look if the constraint is enabled in the tcltest configuration?

Yes. The `testConstraint` command will do that if you don't pass in an argument to set the constraint's status:

```
if {[tcltest::testConstraint foo]} {
    # ...
}
```

But *don't* use this to decide whether to run tests or for-a-single-test setup or cleanup. Tests should always only be turned on or off by constraints directly so that the report generated tcltest can properly track what tests were disabled and for what reasons, and each test has `-setup` and `-cleanup` options that allow for scripts to be run before and after the test *if the constraints are matched*.

---

<sup>Personally, I don't recommend putting tests inside procedures or using a variable for a test name. It works and everything, but it's confusing when you're trying to figure out what test failed and why; debugging is hard enough without adding to it. (I also find that `apply` is *great* as a way to get a procedure-like thing inside a test without losing the “have the code inspectable right there” property.)</sup>

Comment: Hmm, [the documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tcltest.htm) isn't terribly clear that that's what `testConstraint` does.

Comment: Great thanks. In the end I took your advice to avoid having worker procs as it makes the tests more difficult to debug.